# Where do I find cached asp.net pages on the web server?

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis

I add `<%@ OutputCache Location="server" VaryByParam="*"%>` directive asp.net page. The web application is deployed either via Visual Studio Development Server, IIS Express and IIS 7.5 on a local machine. Where can I find the cached files on the machine to verify that different versions of cached pages are generated depends on various query string combination?

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, output caching stores the rendered markup of ASP.NET pages
>   and User Controls in the web server's memory. ...
>   with ASP.NET 4 it is possible to create a custom output cache provider
>   that stores the rendered output elsewhere - to disk, to the cloud, to
>   a distributed caching architecture, etc.

sample :

```
public override void Set(string key, object entry, DateTime utcExpiry)
{
   var item = new DiskOutputCacheItem(this.GetSafeFileName(key), utcExpiry);

   WriteCacheData(item, entry);

   // Add item to CacheItems, if needed, or update the existing key, if it already exists
   lock (_lockObject)
   {
      if (this.CacheItems.ContainsKey(key))
         this.CacheItems[key] = item;
      else
         this.CacheItems.Add(key, item);
   }
}
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121627/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061610-1.aspx

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19835/Creating-a-Custom-Output-Cache-Provider-in-ASPNET-4.htm

Comment: This answer will only be true in one case of the many ways of doing output caching with ASP.NET.

Comment: The files are in memory. if he wants, he can put them in disk. I dont understand your comment. :-)

Comment: @GrantThomas Yes but that case reflects the user's cited example of full page output caching.